# UICollectionView frame changes after hide Nav Bar and Tab Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm trying to keep the `frame` of a `Collection View` that I use as Photo Gallery. But after hide in the view the `UITabBarController` and the `UINavigationController`, its frame changes.

That's the **code** I use for hiding both:

```
- (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];


    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 568, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 568)];
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
            }
        }

    }


    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];

    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 519, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 519)];
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
        {

            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

            }
            else
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
            }
        }

    }



    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)hideNavBar:(UINavigationController *) navBarController
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)showNavBar:(UINavigationController *) navBarController
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Here a image with my problem:

[image]

Thank you very much for your helping

Answer (score 8):

I assume You are using ScrollView to present photos. I've had a simillar problem and setting in your view controller 
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` 
should help.

> Default value is YES, which allows the view controller to adjust
>   its scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed by the
>   status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar. Set to NO if you
>   want to manage scroll view inset adjustments yourself...

Comment: This solution works too when tab bar is hidden using `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;`.